# How to decrypt in Java an encrypted response from PHP?

Tags: java, php, android

**Goal:** I intend to encrypt a JSON response in PHP, and once the android app receives that response, it decrypts it.

I was able to find the Encryption and Decryption functions in PHP:

```
<?php
   function simple_encrypt($text)
    {
    $salt = "anything";
        return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
    }

    function simple_decrypt($text)
    {
        $salt = "anything";
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, base64_decode($text), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)));
    }
?>
```

(I do not actually need the `simple_decrypt` function, I'm just testing it. What I need actually is simply the encryption on server side, and decryption on client side ( my android app) )

So I need a function similar to the simple_decrypt but written in Java so I can decrypt my response.

I have no idea how to do it as I'm very new to Encryption/Decryption. I hope some experts here can guide me to the appropriate solution.

Comment: wouldn't transmission via ssl be easier

Comment: I am using ssl. but I don't know I'd like to encrypt it more. Useless?

Comment: seems like over kill to encrypt it again

Answer (score 0):

[Here is some PHP/Java code I found](http://www.logikdev.com/2010/11/01/encrypt-with-php-decrypt-with-java/) - this is an improvement on your PHP code because it uses Cipher Feedback Mode (CFB), which is more secure than ECB (Electronic Codebook).  To use 256-bit AES in Java you'll need to install the Java Cryptography Extension, available on the bottom of [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).  Note that both the PHP and Java code will need to use the same initialization vector - this should be unique to each ciphertext, but can be transmitted in plaintext.

If you're using SSL then this isn't necessary - you only need to do this if the data is going from PHP to a database / file / some other persistent storage and then to Java.